# Timeit.timeit error (name 'func' is not defined)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried doing `timeit.timeit("func()")` (`func` is a function defined by myself), however, I always get the error `name 'func' is not defined`. Using Jupyter Notebook (I know about the magic timeit of Jupyter, but I wonder why this doesn't work?).

Comment: Please show how you defined func

Comment: @AnnZen: Not the problem, really.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are looking for (without quotes, just directly):

```
timeit.timeit(func, number=1000)
```

instead of

```
timeit.timeit("func()", number=1000)
```

---

To have parameters or other functions, use triple quotes, e.g.:

```
import timeit
import_module = "import whatever_module"
testcode = ''' 
def test():
    # some nasty operations here
    pass
'''
print(timeit.repeat(stmt=testcode, setup=import_module))
```

The code must be self-contained, no external references are allowed.

Comment: How can I pass a parameter that way? I would like to test how long the function takes to execute

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it with first argument a string, that string must contain your full code, e.g.:

```
s = """
def func(n=10000):
    return [x ** 2 for x in range(n)]


func(10000)
"""


timeit.timeit(s)
```

or you need to use the `setup` parameter:

```
s = """
def func(n=10000):
    return [x ** 2 for x in range(n)]
"""


timeit.timeit("func()", setup=s)
```